# Selenium Webdriver is not awaiting properly

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Upon running this test, it doesn't seem to be properly waiting until an element is present before either `sendKeys`, `click` or `submit`, even though I am awaiting a call to `driver.wait` until `elementLocated`.

It also seems to be starting the test, whilst `beforeAll` is still executing.

Async test

```
import { webDriver } from './helpers';
import LoginPage from './pages/loginPage';
import LogoutPage from './pages/logoutPage';
import RolePage from './pages/rolePage';
import PatientSelect from './pages/patientSelect';

describe('example test', () => {
    const driver = webDriver;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        await loginPage.init();
        await loginPage.login('test', 'test1', 50002);

        const rolePage = new RolePage(driver);
        await rolePage.selectRole(2);
    });

    it('should select a patient', async () => {
        const patientSelect = new PatientSelect(driver);
        await patientSelect.searchField('Mary');
        await patientSelect.selectPatient(1);
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        const logoutPage = new LogoutPage(driver);
        await logoutPage.init();
        await logoutPage.logout();
        await driver.quit();
    });
});
```

Base Page Object

```
import { until } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { defaultTimeout } from '../helpers';

export default class BasePage {
    constructor(driver) {
        if (driver == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Expecting an instance of WebDriver');
        }

        this.driver = driver;
    }

    async waitThenGetElement(element) {
        await this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(element), defaultTimeout);
        const elements = await this.driver.findElement(element);
        return elements;
    }

    async waitThenGetElements(element) {
        await this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(element), defaultTimeout);
        const elements = await this.driver.findElements(element);
        return elements;
    }
}
```

Login Page Object

```
import { By, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import BasePage from './basePage';

export default class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    async init() {
        await this.driver.get(`${__ROOT_URI__}/login?return_to=/`);
        await this.driver.wait(until.titleIs('Login'));
    }

    async username(value) {
        const element = await this.waitThenGetElement(By.id('UserName'));
        element.sendKeys(value);
    }

    async password(value) {
        const element = await this.waitThenGetElement(By.id('Password'));
        element.sendKeys(value);
    }

    async cdb(value) {
        const element = await this.waitThenGetElement(By.id('Cdb'));
        element.sendKeys(value);
    }

    async submit() {
        const element = await this.waitThenGetElement(By.className('btn-primary'));
        element.submit();
    }

    async login(username, password, cdb) {
        await this.username(username);
        await this.password(password);
        await this.cdb(cdb);
        await this.submit();
    }
}
```

Patient Select Page Object

```
import { By } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import BasePage from './basePage';

export default class PatientSelect extends BasePage {
    async searchField(value) {
        const element = await this.waitThenGetElement(By.className('form-control'));
        element.sendKeys(value);
    }

    async searchResults() {
        const element = await this.waitThenGetElements(By.className('patient-link'));
        return element;
    }

    async selectPatient(position) {
        const searchResults = await this.searchResults();
        searchResults[position - 1].click();
    }
}
```

Helpers

```
import { Builder } from 'selenium-webdriver';


export const webDriver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

export const defaultTimeout = 10e3;
```

Comment: If I don't wait then execution continues and the promises don't resolve.

Comment: FWIW, I spent about 12 hours banging my head against the wall with this same type of JavaScript-based web automation and async calls, and finally re-wrote the whole thing in Java using Selenium.  Much shorter code, much easier to write using the IDE's autocompletion, and "just works".  That or C# would be my preference with WebDriver stuff.

Comment: @activedecay please read the link provided by yourself https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#option-3-migrate-to-asyncawait